# Why would my electric turn coordinator suddenly stop working?

Tags: aircraft-maintenance

The electric Turn Coordinator in our Cardinal stopped working and we would like to understand the cause.
It simply doesn't move at all, it remain fix.

The red flag is not on, I have double checked the circuit breakers as well.

What could be the cause to that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The motor for the gyro in a Turn Coordinator runs off fixed frequency ac power. For this there is a circuit board in the unit that includes a solid state static inverter to convert the airplane's 12 vdc to ac (110 v at 400 hZ IIRC).  When they just die like that it's usually because the inverter or something else on the circuit board has gone south.

Comment: Thanks, is it a dead unit or can it be repaired ?

Comment: @user1064038 Most things can be repaired. Whether your unit can be repaired economically, or at all, depends on the exact fault. You should contact the manufacturer's nearest service agent.

Comment: If it's one of the newer cheapie plastic short-case TC's that started to appear in the 80s, it's not worth fixing and it's cheaper to replace I believe. If it's an older one with the long metal housing it might be worth fixing.

Answer (score 1):

Regular fault is sticky pivot on indicator 'aeroplane'
Grease/oil hardens and as drive is from gyro gimbals via wire leaf spring 'plane doesnt move although gyro is trying to move it.
Degrease pivot,relube,test.